# What is the sample space of such random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I see a question in Chinese senior high schools books:

> Throwing a fair coin until either there is one Head or four Tails.
>   Find the expectation of times of throwing.
>   (You start throwing a coin, if you see Head, then the game suddenly over; and if you see four Tail, the game is over too. Only these two situation can the game be over.)

(The answer is $1\times\frac{1}{2}+2\times\frac{1}{4}+\cdots=\frac{15}{8}$)

I know that, if we want to calculate the expectation, we, of course, need to find the random variable first. In order to find the random variable, we need to know the sample space of the experiment. However, how can we say about this sample space? The throwing times are varing, not a constant like 3. If the times we throw is 3, the sample space is $\{(a_1,a_2,a_3)\mid \forall 1\le i\le 3,~a_i\in\{H,T\}\}$. But the sample space like this question, is not like this one. What is its sample space?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the problem statement correctly? I don't see the sample space needing to be infinite, as the answer implies; the maximum number of throws required seems to be $4$; either you get 4 tails in a row; if not, you got one head somewhere within the first $4$ throws, which also means you won.

Comment: @Ovi The official solution said that the only four cases are: 1. H   2. TH  3. TTH 4.TTTH 5. TTTT.

Comment: The original question is written in Chinese. Maybe the confusion is due to my poor English. I try to restate the question: you start throwing a coin, if you see Head, then the game suddenly over; and if you see four Tail, the game is over too. Only these two situation can the game be over.

Comment: So, my question is that I don't know how to write down the sample space.

Comment: Ah well when you write $1\times\frac{1}{2}+2\times\frac{1}{4}+\cdots$, the $\cdots$ means it goes on infinitely; when you are adding a finite number of terms it is customary to write the last term after the $\cdots$. Writing down the sample space as $\{H, TH, TTH, TTTH, TTTT \}$ should be fine. Is there a reason why this is not acceptable?

Comment: @Ovi Sorry! I see what you mean. I use $\cdots$ because I'm tired in typing the latter terms, so I skip it. My mistake. Back to our question, so the sample space is $\{H,(T,H),(T,T,H),(T,T,T,H),(T,T,T,T)\}$?

Comment: Yes. The random variable $X$ maps from $\{H, TH, TTH, TTTH, TTTT \}$ to $\{1, 2, 3, 4 \}$, where each element of the sample space is mapped to the number of throws it represents. You have to find the expected value of $X$ using $E(X) = \sum_{x=1}^{4} x \cdot f(x)$

Comment: Your random variable takes values in the set of binary (infinite) sequences $\{T, H\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. You want to compute the size (probability) of the set of sequences that start with either one of the sequences $\{H, TH, TTH, TTTH, TTTT\}$.

Comment: Representing it as $\{(H),(T,H),(T,T,H),(T,T,T,H),(T,T,T,T)\}$ or $\{H, TH, TTH, TTTH, TTTT \}$ shouldn't matter.

Comment: In the space $\{T,H\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ you define a probability by defining it on cylinders $C_J=\{\{a_i\}\in\{T,H\}^{\mathbb{N}}:\ a_j=1\text{ for }j\in J\}$  with $J$ finite, as $P(C_J)=\prod_{j\in J}2^{-j}$.

Comment: I see. If so, then how do we know each of the probabilty of the sample points? I know, for $H$, it is $\frac{1}{2}$; for $(T,H)$, it's $\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}$. This is quite easy that a elemantary student must also know. But from a rigours way in probability theory, if someone saids that the probability of, say $(T,H)$, is  $\frac{1}{4}$, where $4$ is the cardinality of the sample space, how do we debate that he is wrong? At what time the experiment here, and the sample space here, change to refer to others, so that $P(H,T)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: The set that you want to compute probability of can be decomposed as a sum of such cylinders. For example $C_1=\{\{a_i\}\in\{H,T\}^{\mathbb{N}}:\ a_1= H\}$, is the set of sequences in which you get heads in the first throw.

Comment: By the way, the claim by @Ovi that the random variable is a map from $\{H,TH,TTH,TTTH,TTTT\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is incorrect. That is not a what a random variable is and if one were to complete its definition to make it one it would not be the random variable relevant to your problem.

Comment: @Marie Pierre de Le Tetou Can you post an answer? I'm trying to figure out your words, but the symbols takes me time to understand. Can you help be by some concrete (little) numbers? :)

Comment: There is one already there that has all is needed.

Comment: @MariePierredeLeTetou Cold you please elaborate on why my claim is incorrect? I've only taken one probability course, but my book says that a random variable is a function from the outcome space to a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Also, the question is to find the expected value of the number of throws. How does finding $E(X)$, where $X$ maps to the number of throws,  not answer the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take $\Omega=\{T,H\}^4$ as sample space where all outcomes are equiprobable, and prescribe random variable $X$ as the function $\Omega\to\mathbb R$ determined by:

- $X(\omega)=1$ if $\omega_1=H$
- $X(\omega)=2$ if $\omega_1=T$ and $\omega_2=H$
- $X(\omega)=3$ if $\omega_1=\omega_2=T$ and $\omega_3=H$
- $X(\omega)=4$ otherwise

This gives the probabilities:

- $P(X=1)=\frac12$
- $P(X=2)=\frac14$
- $P(X=3)=\frac18$
- $P(X=4)=\frac18$

And expectation: $$\mathbb EX=\sum_{k=1}^4kP(X=k)=1\cdot\frac12+2\cdot\frac14+3\cdot\frac18+4\cdot\frac18=\frac{15}8$$

The probability space is $\langle\Omega,\wp(\Omega),P)$ where $\Omega=\{T,H\}^4$ and probability measure $P$ is defined by: $$P(S)=\frac{|S|}{16}$$

---

Fortunately in situations like this it is not necessary at all to construct a suitable sample space. We can restrict to finding the values of $P(X=k)$ by logical thinking. In many cases even that is not needed when it comes to calculating expectations.

It is a good thing however to **know** about the construction of sample spaces, and for that it is good practice to construct one now and then.

Comment: The definition of expectation is $E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^kx_iP(X=x_i)$. Since $X$ is a function on $\Omega$, every element should have the function value defined on it. How do we define the value of, say $(H,T,H,T)$? Is $4$?

Comment: $X(H,T,H,T)=1$ since here $\omega_1=H$. The outcomes have the form $(\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\omega_4)$ where $\omega_i\in\{H,T\}$ for $i=1,2,3,4$. In my answer $X(\omega)$ is indeed defined for every $\omega\in\Omega$.

Comment: So the $P(X,T,H,T)$ is $1\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2$ over $2^4$ right?

Comment: $P(X,T,H,T)$ is a confusing notation here. There are $16$ equiprobable outcomes and $1\times2\times2\times2$ of them have $\omega_1=H$, so $P(X=1)=\frac{8}{16}=\frac12$.

Comment: Oh yes! I see. I was too careless about the notation, but I know what you say! Let me try to calculate another one: for $P(X=3)$, it is $\frac{1\times 1\times 1\times 2}{2\times 2\times 2\times 2}=\frac{1}{8}$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct (and agrees with my answer).

Comment: Thank you very much. :) By the way, can you recommend me some good probability books? I trust you. :)

Comment: You're welcome. I am too much an autodidact for that. I learned this at university by means of scripts and cannot assist you when it comes to references. If you have teacher, then trust him/her too and ask him/her :-).

Answer (score 1):

You can use as a sample space the set
$$
    \Omega=\left\{H,TH,TTH,TTTH,TTTT\right\}
$$
The probabilities of these outcomes are $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{1}{8}$, $\frac{1}{16}$, and $\frac{1}{16}$ respectively.

[You asked how to show this rigorously.  Each throw is independent from every other throw, and on each throw the probability of $H$ or $T$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.  The probability of independent events is the product of the probabilities of each of those events.]

Let $X$ be the number of throws in each outcome.  That's just the length of the word: 
\begin{align*}
    X(H) &= 1 \\
    X(TH) &= 2 \\
    X(TTH) &= 3 \\
    X(TTTH) &= 4 \\
    X(TTTT) &= 4
\end{align*}
So the expected value is:
$$
    E(X) = 1 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
          +2 \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)
          +3 \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)
          +4 \left(\frac{1}{16}\right)
          +4 \left(\frac{1}{16}\right)
         = \frac{15}{8}
$$